# Python-Selenium find element based on it sibling element value

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Html code looks like this.

```
<div>
  <span>Title</span>
  <input value="a">
</div>
<div>
  <span>Price</span>
  <input value="">
</div>
```

I need to check if Span is price then insert value for Price etc...

Basically I can access to all inputs like

```
for el in driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value="//input"):
    try:
        if el.parent.span... == 'Price':  #HERE I NEED TO ADD MISSING PART
           el.send_keys('10')
    except:
        pass
```

But then I can't determine upper node value.

Also tried with :

```
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//input/preceding-sibling::span[contains(.,'Price')]")
```

Like this I'm able to locate Span element but I need to insert price in INPUT.

Since this is only snippet from a way bigger code where class names positions etc. are dynamically generated. I need to go this way.

Comment: Your question is not so clear for me. Do you want to insert the value inside the `input` where `span` contains text `Price` or this block also must be below the block with `Title`?

Comment: I need to insert value in the input field where span contains text Price.  So, span `Price` and `input` are both inside the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can locate the `input` element based on it `span` sibling text content value as following:

```
"//div[contains(.,'Price')]//input"
```

(There are more ways to do that).
So your Selenium code can be as following:

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(.,'Price')]//input").send_keys('10')
```

In case `<span>Price</span>` is a direct child of the parent `div` we can make the locator more precise, as following:

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[./span[contains(text(),'Price')]]//input").send_keys('10')
```

Briefly explanations:
With XPath we can locate elements by any it attributes.
Here we can locate the parent `div` based on the fact it contains a direct `span` child element containing the `Price` text.
So, `span[contains(text(),'Price')]` will match a `span` with `Price` text content while `//div[./span[contains(text(),'Price')]]` literally says:
"Find somewhere `//` an element with `div` tag name so that inside it (this is why a dot `.` is used there) a direct child `/` is `span` whos text content is `Price`".
Once we have this `div` we can find it `input` child by `//input`.
So simple.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. WIth this xPath `driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//input")` I got 8 members same as with this `driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(.,'Price')]//input")` It filters me all //inputs but I need to get only the one with span above titled Price.

Comment: I see.. 2 clarification questions: does `div` containing these `span` and `input` nodes have any unique class or something unique? And are `span` and `input` are direct children of that parent `div`?

Comment: In case `<span>Price</span>` is a direct child of the parent `div` the updated answer should work. Please add the clarifications I asked about.

Comment: yes. The updated answer works fine now.  If you have any documentation to point me where to practice this xPaths or briefly explanation . Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm not sure about good, clear and simple documentations, so I added some explanations. I hope it is clear.

Comment: In case something is still not clear - let me know. I will be happy to clarify.